# PHP & post Youtube ID to another page

Tags: php, post, youtube, embed

I've been searching for this a lot but have not found exactly what I'm looking for.

So, I have a page (`index.php`) which displays my YouTube channel's uploaded videos as thumbnails, and either displays them inline above the thumbnails, or as links that redirect to Youtube. What I'd like to do, is to get the video's ID (which is in the a href link) and post it to another page (`video.php`) that shows the full embedded video (of the `ID` in question), with title & description. Is this possible to do?

My site is loosely based on this: http://www.yvoschaap.com/youtube.html and I've tried Youmax, but like said, they only play videos inline. I want to pass the ID of a clicked video as a parameter to the video.php page.

Sorry if this is confusing, but I'm still quite new to programming :)

Comment: Please can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

The main link you will need to retreive a list of all Videos for a channel will be somewhat like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults={number_of_videos_you_want}
```

It will recieve it's response in JSON Format containing information like your Video ID which you can pass as Parameter to your video.php page